# UIImageView outlet nil in custom UIView with xib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, xib

I've created a custom `UIView` with multiple IBOutlets including a UIImageView, and three `UILabel`s. Despite setting the image value in the awakeFromNib() function, I'm still getting a nil value for the outlet when attempting to set it. The `UIView` was constructed using a custom xib file.

I put the set operation in `awakeFromNib()` so as to assure the outlets had been initialized prior to setting them, yet this failed to help. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the xib file as I've only ever used custom xibs when making a custom table cell, so perhaps the issue is rooted there?

```
class VotingCard: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var proPicImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hometownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!

    var proPic = UIImage()
    var name = ""
    var hometown = ""
    var rating = 0.0

    init(pic: UIImage, rush: Rush) {
        proPic = pic
        name = rush.fullName
        hometown = rush.homeTown
        rating = rush.compositeRating
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300))
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        proPicImg.image = proPic
        nameLabel.text = name
        hometownLabel.text = hometown
        ratingLabel.text = "\(rating)"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I should view a simple card with the profile image and respective data visible, yet instead it crashes.

Comment: How are you instantiating your view?

Comment: let v = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VotingCard", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! VotingCard, then I set the various properties with this object (not the iboutlets themselves but variables in their place), in awakeFromNib() I set the outlet values to the value of these variables

Comment: try to create a new XIB and class and don't use anything from old, means do not copy anything like the label or image anything start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

NIB-based development is sort-of deprecated:

> For iOS developers, using storyboards is the recommended way to design
>   user interfaces.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/NibFile.html

But, looks like you're missing this step:

> At runtime, you load a nib file using the method `loadNibNamed:owner:`
>   or a variant thereof. The File’s Owner is a placeholder in the nib
>   file for the object that you pass as the owner parameter of that
>   method. Whatever connections you establish to and from the File’s
>   Owner in the nib file in Interface Builder are reestablished when you
>   load the file at runtime.

See as an example:

https://medium.com/@umairhassanbaig/ios-swift-creating-a-custom-view-with-xib-ace878cd41c5

If you want to do it the recommended way with Storyboard (apparently not, but this is for general audience):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html

> viewDidLoad()—Called when the view controller’s content view (the top
>   of its view hierarchy) is created and loaded from a storyboard. The
>   view controller’s outlets are guaranteed to have valid values by the
>   time this method is called. Use this method to perform any additional
>   setup required by your view controller.

So with the `UIViewController` method, put your code in `viewDidLoad()` instead.

Keep in mind this is *always* called, so this will overwrite the work of your custom `init()` function. Perhaps this is what you were running into.

I would refactor it to avoid ugly code. Create the `Rush` object always (declare as Optional as stored property), but initialize it in awakeFromNib() for the XIB case, and copy the input object in the custom-init case.

Then `viewDidLoad()` has no conditionals.

Comment: This makes sense, but my intention was to make a custom UIView, not UIViewController, and I believe the UIView does not have a viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is either

1-The imageView isn't connected to Ib , and the fix is to connect it

**Or**

2- You create an object of the view with  `init(pic: UIImage, rush: Rush) {` and that for sure won't load the UI with view , hence all outlets are nil , and the fix to add this method

```
class func getInstance(_ pic: UIImage, rush: Rush) -> VotingCard { 
   let v = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("VotingCard", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! VotingCard 
   v.proPic = pic
   v.name = rush.fullName
   v.hometown = rush.homeTown
   v.rating = rush.compositeRating
   return v
}
```

Call

```
let v = VotingCard.getInstance(<#image#>,rush:<#rush#>)
v.frame = // set some frame
// ready for use
```

Comment: Well out with one problem on with another, I'm now getting the error this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ___. I'm familiar with this error as being caused by bad outlet connections but I've now several times deleted and recreated my xib connections and yet the problem persists.

Comment: look deeper for that key name , and search all outlets

Comment: Is there any other issue that could cause this to occur? I found that when I simply removed the troublesome outlet, I simply got the same error for the next outlet, I did a complete removal of all outlets and failed to solve it so i'm wondering if there's some foundational error I'm missing in my xib file

Comment: make sure that you assign the class and drag all outlets from the begining

Comment: Yup the class is correct and tried the connections again, still no luck.